# What is dhatu roop for हासिषु

Tags: vedas, sanskrit

Various vedic chants contain the word हासिषु in phrases like मा मा हासिषु which translates to don't abandon me like सत्यम् मा माहासिषु which means May Truth not abandon me however I am unable to find dhatu roop for हासिषु , it resembles बहुवचन अधिकरण कारक. Is it that vedic samskrit has its own syntax which differs from samskrit we speak ?

Comment: Pure Sanskrit language questions are off-topic. Check [Should we close questions related to Sanskrit language and grammar as off-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/748/3500)

Comment: "Various vedic chants contain the word हासिषु ". If you want to know meaning (or Nirukta meaning) of word  "हासिषु" in any Veda mantra, you can quote that mantra and ask for meaning,

Comment: I want to know dhatu of हासिषु like dhatu for भरति is भृ .